# Store HTML and CSS of target container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web-storage

I have a container `div` containing some html - for example:

```
<div id="container">
     <h1>Bla bla</h1>
     <div class="myItem"></div>
     <a href="#">Send</a>
</div>
```

and some css related to the container:

```
#container {background:red;}
#container h1 {font-size:30px;}
#container .myItem {color:red;font-size:12px;}
```

I would like to store all the html inside the container and all the related css to it in some variable/database/whatever is available, and then load it back on a new page. The content is dynamic and it's up to the user to style the container and it's content.

How could I accomplish this? One way I was thinking was to retrieve all this properties using javascript and than store them somehow in the database to load them back later or try to do this with html5 webstorage.

Is there any plugin that does this?

EDIT:
I've also tried html2canvas but it's support for css3 is not good enough to render the elements correctly.

Comment: Does it need to be saved over several requests or do you only want it to be stored and use it in a single page?

Comment: @giorgio - the exact case is a box that the user can rotate - done with css3 matrix and jqCube plugin - to that box the user applies different background images and colors - once he hits save it saves it to the gallery of all designed boxes - the gallery loads on a new page - but within the same domain.

Comment: try chenge block ID/class by JQ

Comment: Is the CSS you need to save present on the page? If it is, it shouldn't be difficult to do this with some JS/jQuery. You could save it to localStorage, as you said, in this way.

Answer (score 1):

If the CSS and HTML are both stored within the page, you can just grab the content (based on the wrapper) and store it in localStorage (if this works for your purpose).

An example with jQuery and localStorage... you will need to change where things are being saved from to fit your case.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57bpg/)

Saving the items:

```
var html = $('#container').html();
localStorage.setItem('html', html);

var css = $('#csscontainer').html();
localStorage.setItem('css', css);
```

Pulling/showing the items:

```
var showHtml = localStorage.getItem('html');
var showCss = localStorage.getItem('css');

$('#showHtml').html(showHtml);
$('#showCss').html(showCss);
```

Comment: Huh this is much more simple than I thought - good sample - will try this out first.

Comment: A note about web storage: localStorage persists even when the session ends (i.e. the user closes the browser). sessionStorage throws out the data when the session ends. The example above uses localStorage... you can just change "local" to "session" if you want the data to be less persistent. Here is a nice description: [web storage](http://sixrevisions.com/html/introduction-web-storage/)